# Promise resolve() doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, sapui5

NB: this javascript uses the openui5 libraries

```
attachOnceAsync: function(binding, callback) {
  var args = [...arguments]
  args.splice(0, 2)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var dataReceived = function(oEvent) {
      if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        if (callback.constructor.name === "AsyncFunction") {
          callback(oEvent, ...args).then(() =>
            resolve(oEvent)
          ).catch((err) => {
            reject(err)
          })
        } else {
          try {
            callback(oEvent, ...args);
            resolve(oEvent)
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err)
          }
        }
      } else {
        resolve(oEvent, ...args);
      }
    }
    binding.attachEventOnce("dataReceived", dataReceived);
  })
}
```

There aren't any Promise versions of events like "dataReceived" so this is my attempt to wrap one up.

In this case, callback is undefined (it shouldn't be, but that's a different issue). The line resolve(oEvent, ...args); is hit instead, only it never returns out of the await!

I changed that line to just resolve(oEvent) but still no joy.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

PS: I'll keep an eye on this question so I can offer any extra info required

here's how I call it:

```
handleAsync: async function(controller) {
  
  /* Lots of setup */

  var response = await fetch(/*redacted*/ )

  if (response.status === 400) {
    console.log(await response.json());
    throw new BadRequestException();
  }

  if (response.status === 204){
   
    /* more setup */

    context = oPanel.getBindingContext("odata");

    var updatePurchaseOrderDocTotalFunc = this.updatePurchaseOrderDocTotal
    var callback = async function() {
      
      var docTotalUpdate = await updatePurchaseOrderDocTotalFunc(oView, context, oModel, agreedPrice);
    
      if (docTotalUpdate && docTotalUpdate.status === 204) {
        await context.refresh();
      }
    }

    //-- HERE --
    await AsyncBinding.attachOnceAsync(binding,callback)
    
    await context.refresh();
  }       
  return true;   
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `attachOnceAsync` is called?

Comment: Is `dataReceived` event actually fired, if you put a `console.log` inside you `dataReceived` callback do you get anything.  Also `resolve(oEvent, ...args);`  resolve doesn't take args, if you want to resolve more place inside an object -> `resolve({oEvent, args:...args})`

Comment: @raina77ow Added "how its called"

Comment: @Keith dataReceived function does run.  It even gets to the last resolve, or am I missing something asynchronous? - Yeah I saw that about ...args.  I've just removed it for now

Comment: What's `binding`? Also, can you add some logs right after `await AsyncBinding.attachOnceAsync(...)` line?

Comment: @raina77ow binding is a very OpenUI5 type but it's essentially an oData binding in this case.  You can "bind" a "view" to odata.  In this case I get the binding from the view, attachOnce on the dataReceived and then call update on the binding.  It will fetch the odata again and fire the dataReceived event.
I'll add some logging and post back

Comment: I think your code looks way more complicated than if you simply used the binding and the events as they already exist. Would be interesting to see what bigger problem you are trying to solve, because right now you are creating a bigger problem. Manually calling `fetch` when dealing with OData is already a code smell imo.

Comment: @Marc To put it simply, SAP odata is somewhat lacking, hence the mix of odata and api calls.

Comment: @Marc Several activities happen in order in certain cases.  During these activities the view is set to "busy".  Rather than have loose events be triggered, it makes more sence to use the async/await pattern.  It works fine for other binding types, just not this one case.

Comment: Not to sound rude but if SAP odata is somewhat lacking then the issue might me a lack of understanding the provided classes ;) That's why I wanted to know the use case. If you want your view to be busy implement a proper view model, set its state to busy in `dataRequested` and unbusy in `dataReceived`. Do your binding directly in the XML then the table/list will automatically become busy while fetching data.

Comment: Would be easiest if you created a small sample so we could try and improve it. Right now we are just seeing some undreadable code snippets.

Comment: @Marc not rude at all ^_^
so several things happen in a chain of events, depending on what's changed.  We tried setBusy(true) and setBusy(false) at the start and end of each process, but as they overlap the first setBusy(true) overrides all else.  I created a "busyStack" class that returns a function to pop off the stack.  I can't pass that between event handlers, hence the await async approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - The answer was staring at me.

Sorry I wasn't able to provide a working snippet but the ui5 scripts are quite extensive.

I have several other functions that return a Promise so I can use the await/async approach, but with this one I forgot to include the action that causes the event to fire.

I renamed the function to show what it now does, and included the action that causes the event to fire:

```
RefreshAsync :  function(context,binding, callback){
  var args = [...arguments]
  args.splice(0,2)

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var dataReceived = function(oEvent){  
        if(typeof callback == 'function' ){
            if(callback.constructor.name==="AsyncFunction"){
                callback(oEvent, ...args).then(()=>{                          
                    resolve(oEvent)
                }).catch((err)=>{                          
                    reject(err)
                })
            }else{
                try{
                    callback(oEvent, ...args);                         
                    resolve(oEvent)
                }catch(err){                          
                    reject(err)
                }
            }
        }else{                         
            resolve([oEvent, ..args])
        }
    }
    binding.attachEventOnce("dataReceived", dataReceived);
    
    //This is the action I missed
    context.Refresh()
  })
},
```